# Preenchendo linhas com os dados corretos em R, juntando linhas sucessivas

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho uma base de dados com a segunte estrutura:

```
a=as.data.frame(tribble(  
  ~a, ~texto, ~x2007, ~x2008,  
  "a","aa",0,0,  
   0,"--",12,13,  
  "b","bb",1,2,  
  "c","cc", 0, 0,  
  0,"dd", 0,0,  
  0,"ee",7,8))
```

As linhas que começam com zero são a continuação das linhas que iniciam com letra, imediatamente anterior e os dados para a terceira e quarta colunas são os dados que estão na terceira e quarta coluna da última linha que começa com zero (os dados da linha 4 estão no final da linha 6.
Além disso, os dados da coluna 2 precisam ser combinados. O resultado desejado seria:

```
  a texto x2007 x2008  
1 a aa --      12    13  
3 b    bb       1     2  
4 c cc dd ee    5     6
```

Tentei o seguinte:

```
b=vector()  
for (i in 2:nrow(a)) {  
  if(a[i,1]==0) {  
    a[i-1,2]=paste(a[i-1,2],a[i,2])  
    a[i-1,3:4]=a[i,3:4]  
    b=c(b,i)  
    }  
}  
a=a[-b,]  #exclui linhas
```

mas só funciona para duas linha consecutivas:

```
  a texto x2007 x2008
1 a aa --    12    13
3 b    bb     1     2
4 c cc dd     5     6
```

alguém pode me ajudar ou tem uma solução mais simples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possível solução é a seguinte.
Usa uma função do pacote `zoo` para modificar a coluna `a` e depois de terminado volta a os por zeros onde estavam.

```
zeros <- a$a == 0
is.na(a$a) <- zeros
a$a <- zoo::na.locf(a$a)

res <- lapply(split(a, a$a), function(DF){
  data.frame(a = DF$a[1],
             texto = paste(DF$texto, collapse = " "),
             x2007 = max(DF$x2007),
             x2008 = max(DF$x2008))
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#  a    texto x2007 x2008
#1 a    aa --    12    13
#2 b       bb     1     2
#3 c cc dd ee     7     8

a$a[zeros] <- 0
a
```